# Laravel filter nested collection returns duplicated results

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to filter an existing collection to avoid querying database non-stop. As far as I understand, **re-using an existing collection does not perform any query in the database**, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Unfortunately the results given by the filter are not similiar with the normal query function.

Three tables only:

```
Clients (id, name)
Products (id, name)
ProductsClients (product_id, client_id)
```

The main function that works flawless:

```
public function findAll($productsIds)
{
    $this->clients = Clients::with(['products' => function($query) use($productsIds)
        {
            $query->whereIn('product_id', $productsIds);
        }])
        ->whereHas('products', function($query) use ($productsIds)
        {
            $query->where('active', true)
                ->whereIn('product_id', $productsIds);
        })
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
        ->get();
}
```

The following illustrates my problem:

```
ProductsClients table sample:
(1000, 1)
(1001, 1)
(1000, 2);
(1002, 2);

Input sample:
Customer 1 : has [1000, 1001] : misses [1002]
Customer 2 : has [1000, 1002] : misses [1001]

Output sample:
Customer 1 : [1000, 1001] + [1002]
Customer 2 : [1000, 1002] + [1001]
```

The function to perform query operations within the collection:

```
private function findInCollection($productsIds)
{
    return $this->clients->filter(function($client) use ($productsIds)
    {
        return $client->products->whereIn('product_id', $productsIds)->count() > 0;
    })->all();
}
```

And the logic I have to grab the missing id's:

```
foreach ($this->clients as $client)
{
    $missingProductsIds = [...]; // Will be 1002 & 1001 respectively
    $fromOtherClient = $this->findInCollection($missingProductsIds); 
}

Current (wrong) output:
Customer 1 : [1000, 1001] + [1000, 1001] + [1002]
Customer 2 : [1000, 1002] + [1000, 1002] + [1001]
```

So, it's returning the initial input plus the correct value I'm looking for.

If instead of `$fromOtherClient = $this->findInCollection($missingProductsIds);`  I use `$fromOtherClient = $this->findAll($missingProductsIds);` it works great.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have different conditions in your `with()` and `whereHas()` closures? Also if you're searching for certain product IDs, your query might better start with `Products::whereIn('id', $productsIds)...`

Comment: @miken32 yes, clients can have 1000 products, but the search being done is only on 3 products, that's why apart from `whereHas`, the `with()` is also filtered / required.

Comment: Typically the same conditions are provided to both `with()` and `whereHas()`. Your question isn't very clear on what specific output you're looking for. Are you trying to find the products that a client doesn't have? Providing representative database rows as well as explaining the model relationships would also be helpful here.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find the products that a client doesn't have but only within the initial range of products ids provided. In this case, the range is [1000, 1001, 1002].

Comment: I don't understand your closing sentence, the two methods appear to do completely different things but you're suggesting that one does what you want.

Comment: Are you saying you run the query to populate a collection and then you want to search that collection to find out which items from the list are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to understand your requirements, but if I have it right you'll need to loop through each item in the collection, pull out the list of product ids, and then diff it against the list of ids you're looking for. Something like this:

```php
private function findInCollection(array $productsIds): Collection
{
    return $this->clients->mapWithKeys(function($client) use ($productsIds) {
        return [
            $client->id => collect($productIds)
                ->diff($client->products->pluck("id"))
                ->values()
                ->toArray();
        ];
    });
}
```

The returned collection will be indexed by client ID.

---

Here's some proof of concept code that illustrates the technique:

```php
$clients = collect([
    collect(["id" => 1, "products" => collect([["id" => 1000, "name" => "Product 1000"], ["id" => 1001, "name" => "Product 1001"], ["id" => 1003, "name" => "Product 1003"]]), "name" => "Client 1"]),
    collect(["id" => 2, "products" => collect([["id" => 1000, "name" => "Product 1000"], ["id" => 1002, "name" => "Product 1002"], ["id" => 1003, "name" => "Product 1003"]]), "name" => "Client 2"]),
]);
$productIds = [1000, 1001, 1002];

$missing = $clients->mapWithKeys(function ($v) use ($productIds) {
    return [$v["id"] => collect($productIds)->diff($v["products"]->pluck("id"))->values()->toArray()];
});

dump($missing);
```

Output:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#5133
  #items: array:2 [
    1 => array:1 [
      0 => 1002
    ]
    2 => array:1 [
      0 => 1001
    ]
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```